# What is the proper way to do a foreach loop with an Array/Map in dart?

Tags: php, dart

I'm trying to convert a piece of PHP code to dart and getting stuck.
What I have is a PHP array `text` that gets run through a function called `toUTF8` as follows:

```
if(is_array($text))
{
  foreach($text as $k => $v)
    {
    text[$k] = self::toUTF8($v);
    }
  return $text;
}
```

Conceptually, what I've done in dart is turn text into a `Map`

```
if(text is Map)
{
  foreach(text as k => v)
    {
    text[k] = toUTF8(v);
    }
  return text;
}
```

But I cannot wrap my mind around, how I would walk the map and run each element into the toUTF8 function.

Essentially, the question is how to do a foreach on a map?

For bonus points, would treating it as a `List` is a better approach?  What this code is ultimately doing is handling malformed UTF8 characters

Comment: Is the code not working?

Comment: `for (var key in map.keys) { map[key] = toUTF8(map[key]!); }`.  Alternatively, if you want to create a new `Map` object: `var newMap = oldMap.map((key, value) => MapEntry(key, toUTF8(value)));`.

Comment: What is the content of `text`? Is it an array of strings? (In that case, you probably don't want to store the UTF-8 representation back into the same collection in Dart, that's not well-typed.)

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably keep it as an array. I don't see any good reason for using a map.

What are the contents of the `text` array? Is it strings or UTF-8 bytes? Is it individual string characters, or longer strings?
Since you call something called `toUTF8`, I'm assuming it's strings, and you want to convert them to UTF-8.
I'm not sure how the code "handles" malformed UTF-8 sequences, since it appears to convert *to* UTF-8.

You are doing that on a chunk-by-chunk basis, but that's not necessarily correct, if the `text` array represents a single large text chopped into pieces. Dart strings are sequences of UTF-16 code units, and a surrogate pair  can be split between separate chunks, but must be converted together.

I'd do something like:

```dart
var bytes = Stream.fromIterable(text).transform(utf8.encoder);
// do something with `bytes`.
```

or, if you want manual control:

```dart
import "dart:convert";
import "dart:typed_data";
// ...
  var buffer = BytesBuilder();
  var converter = utf8.encoder.startChunkedEncoding(
      ByteConversionSink.withCallback(buffer.add));
  text.forEach(converter.add);
  converter.close();
  var bytes = buffer.takeBytes(); // UTF-8 converted `text`.
```